# Egg Yolk Riddle

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, english, language

I remember this from when I was in highschool (or the dutch equivolant).
The teacher of my english class proposed this riddle and a lot of people had it wrong but the answer was really simple. Remember in holland english isn't our native language.

What is the correct sentence?

"The egg yolk is white"

or

"The egg yolk are white"

Have fun and don't spoil

> Look at the mistakes in the text, they are there for a reason :)

Comment: I didn't downvote (not enough rep), but my guess would be because it's not good.

Comment: I think the puzzle would be clearer if the question would have been put at its end rather than in the center. It sometimes is hard to differ between puzzle and mistake...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All sentences are incorrect except for *"What is the correct sentence?"*.

> Look at the mistakes: *"dutch"*, *"english"* and *"holland"* should have their first letter capitalized. *"equivolant"* is a misspelling of equivalent.
>  Also: the egg yolk is singular and it's not white; and the last sentence is missing a period at the end.

Comment: So what is the correct sentence?

Comment: @Wouter Ok, I think I got it right now. Funny riddle!

Comment: I edited the question to fix up the typos, then saw your answer and had to do a hasty rollback! I bet others are going to do that as well...

Comment: Technically, "Which is the correct sentence?" is more correct than "What is", as you're being asked to select from a list of options :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah I'm pretty fluent in English if I say so myself, but most people will see that as incorrect spelling or an incorrect use of caps :) thanks for the comment though

Answer (score 5):

> "Neither, the egg yolk is yellow" would be the correct answer, if it was not a trick question.

Comment: This would be the original but I made mine differs because I put it in to throw off the solver :P

Comment: Haha, now I see the answer. I thought the mistakes were unintentional!

Comment: Haha nope, but well that's why i got the downvotes apparently

Answer (score 0):

> It's a trick question, neither is correct. Egg yolk is yellow.